# PHP mi inicio de sesion siempre pasa da igual la contraseña que ponga

Tags: php7

Buenas estoy creando un pequeño `formulario` en `html` de **inicio de sesion** ni siquiera esta conectado a una base de datos **tengo hardcodeado las credenciales que deben ser las correctas para iniciar sesion** pues solo trato de entender las `$_SESSION`.

A ver tengo un simple **formulario de inicio de sesion**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="uno.php" >
        Nombre Usuario <input type="text" name="usuario"><br>
        Password <input type="password" name="contrasena"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Un **fichero de comprobacion del inicio de sesion** (uno.php):

```
<?php 

$user  = "jose";
$password = "jose";

if (isset($_POST['usuario']) == $user && isset($_POST['contrasena']) == $password ) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = "jose";
    $_SESSION['pais'] = "España";
    header("location: dos.php");
}
else{
    echo "Su nombre USUARIO o CONTRASEÑA es incorrecta, intentelo de nuevo. <br>";

    echo "<a href='form.php'>INTENTAR NUEVAMENTE</a>";
}

 ?>
```

Lo que entiendo que hace ese fichero es lo siguiente : 
Si las variables `usuario` y `contrasena` enviada desde **POST** no estan **vacias** y ademas **son iguales a mis dos variables** `$user` y `$password` pues creame una **sesion** con esos datos y **redirijeme** a la pagina `dos.php`. 
En cambio si **no coinciden** mandame un error y crea un enlace que me redirige al `form` nuevamente.

Mi fichero `dos.php` es :

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    echo "BIENVENIDO ". $_SESSION['usuario'];   

 ?>
```

Simplente que de la bienvenida al usuario.

El **problema** es que da igual lo que ponga en el formulario entra en mi fichero `dos.php`

Answer (score 2):

Tu error está dentro del if con las comparaciones. Concretamente en el uso de la función isset.

Esta función retorna TRUE / FALSE dependiendo de si la variable está o no definida. Aunque esta sea FALSE, 0, etc..(pero eso ya es otro asunto).

Lo que deberías hacer no es evaluar si dichas variables están definidas (eso deberías hacerlo, pero hacerlo antes del if), sino simplemente comparar si ambos valores son iguales, es decir:

```
if ($_POST['usuario'] == $user && $_POST['contrasena'] == $password ) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = "jose";
    $_SESSION['pais'] = "España";
    header("location: dos.php");
}
```

Es decir, estás mezclando dos cosas: una cosa es que las variables $_POST que te llegan del envío del formulario estén definidas y otra diferente es que sean iguales a los valores que recuperas de la DB.

Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(!isset($_POST['usuario'] || !isset($_POST['contrasena']){
//la función isset() retorna FALSE sobre esa(s) variable(s), es decir, ni siquiera está(n) definida(s), lo cual quiere decir que no ha(n) llegado.
//actuas en consecuencia, como tu desees
}

$user  = "jose";
$password = "jose";

//si el código llega a este punto es que ambas variable están definidas. Ahora 
//que ya tienes la seguridad de que han llegado puedes hacer la comparación

    if ($_POST['usuario'] == $user && $_POST['contrasena'] == $password ) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = "jose";
        $_SESSION['pais'] = "España";
        header("location: dos.php");
    }
else{
    echo "Su nombre USUARIO o CONTRASEÑA es incorrecta, intentelo de nuevo. <br>";

    echo "<a href='form.php'>INTENTAR NUEVAMENTE</a>";
}
```

Espero habertelo aclarado.

Comment: pero no entiendo porque no puedo poner el **isset**

Comment: Claro pero yo quiero ambos requerimientos, por **por una parte** quiero que los valores que me llegan del **POST** del form no esten vacias, por eso uso **isset** y por otro lado las **comparo** con las variables que tengo arriba y asi simular **la verificacion de usuario**

Comment: @josanangel puedes incluir el isset dentro de tu código (de hecho, deberías, para comprobar que efectivamente lo que esperas que llegue efectivamente te llega), pero la comprobación de que ambas variables existen deberías hacerla antes de la comparación. Edito mi respuesta para que veas a que me refiero.

Comment: de acuerdo, pero veo practicamente en todos los codigo el uso del `if(isset($_POST[]))`

Answer (score 2):

El problema está, como te han comentado es tu comprobación del `if`, la función `isset` devuelve un *boolean* (true o false). Y estas comparando true/false con `$user` o $contrasena y eso no es correcto.

Puedes hacer una comprobación para saber si vienen informado las variables del formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
if(!isset($_POST['usuario']))
{
    echo "El nombre de usuario es obligatorio<br>";
    echo "<a href='form.php'>Volver</a>";
    die();
}

if(!isset($_POST['contrasena']))
{
    echo "La contraseña es obligatorio<br>";
    echo "<a href='form.php'>Volver</a>";
    die();
}
```

Con esto averiguas que el usuario y la contraseña mandadas desde el formulario no estén vacías. En ese caso muestras una acción volver para poder introducir los datos nuevamente.

Ahora es cuando puedes comparar los datos de tu formulario con las variables declaradas arriba.

```
if ($_POST['usuario']) == $user && $_POST['contrasena'] == $password ) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = "jose";
    $_SESSION['pais'] = "España";
    header("location: dos.php");
}
else{
    echo "Su nombre USUARIO o CONTRASEÑA es incorrecta, intentelo de nuevo. <br>";

    echo "<a href='form.php'>INTENTAR NUEVAMENTE</a>";
}
```

Código completo quedaría así:

```
if(!isset($_POST['usuario']))
    {
        echo "El nombre de usuario es obligatorio<br>";
        echo "<a href='form.php'>Volver</a>";
        die();
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['contrasena']))
    {
        echo "La contraseña es obligatorio<br>";
        echo "<a href='form.php'>Volver</a>";
        die();
    }


    if ($_POST['usuario']) == $user && $_POST['contrasena'] == $password ) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = "jose";
        $_SESSION['pais'] = "España";
        header("location: dos.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "Su nombre USUARIO o CONTRASEÑA es incorrecta, intentelo de nuevo. <br>";

        echo "<a href='form.php'>INTENTAR NUEVAMENTE</a>";
    }

 ?>
```

No es la manera mas optima de hacerlo, pero puede serte de utilidad.

Comment: Y porque no se puede hacer de un paso? yo siempre he visto el if isset